# Display the time in a different time zone

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone

Is there an elegant way to display the current time in another time zone?

I would like to have something with the general spirit of:

```
cur = <Get the current time, perhaps datetime.datetime.now()>
print("Local time   {}".format(cur))
print("Pacific time {}".format(<something like cur.tz('PST')>))
print("Israeli time {}".format(<something like cur.tz('IST')>))
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117514/how-do-i-use-timezones-with-a-datetime-object-in-python

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find it when I searched for the topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use timezones with a datetime object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117514/how-do-i-use-timezones-with-a-datetime-object-in-python)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could use the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> utc = pytz.utc
>>> utc.zone
'UTC'
>>> eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> eastern.zone
'US/Eastern'
>>> amsterdam = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

>>> loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
>>> print loc_dt.strftime(fmt)
2002-10-27 06:00:00 EST-0500

>>> ams_dt = loc_dt.astimezone(amsterdam)
>>> ams_dt.strftime(fmt)
'2002-10-27 12:00:00 CET+0100'
```

Comment: For the 'current time' part of the question, you could start with `loc_dt = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())` instead of a constant

Comment: @patricksurry: the "current time" part is answered in [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096669/4279)

Comment: I dont want ot use external library. I want to use only native library. then how should I do?

Comment: In 2021 [this is the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/6560549)

Comment: Python 3.9+ has a new module in the **standard** library, called [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). No need for external dependencies like [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) anymore.

Answer (score 146):

A simpler method:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone    

south_africa = timezone('Africa/Johannesburg')
sa_time = datetime.now(south_africa)
print sa_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
```

Comment: I dont want ot use external library. I want to use only native library. then how should I do?

Comment: pytz and datetime are native libraries

Comment: @DavidB. nope, `pytz` is a third party library. Luckily, `zoneinfo` comes with the standard lib of Python 3.9, see my answer ;-)

Comment: Python 3.9+ has a new module in the **standard** library, called [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). No need for external dependencies like [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) anymore.

Answer (score 52):

**Python 3.9** (or higher): use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) from the standard lib:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

# Israel and US/Pacific time:
now_Israel = datetime.now(ZoneInfo('Israel'))
now_Pacific = datetime.now(ZoneInfo('US/Pacific'))
print(f"Israeli time {now_Israel.isoformat(timespec='seconds')}")
print(f"Pacific time {now_Pacific.isoformat(timespec='seconds')}")
# Israeli time 2021-03-26T18:09:18+03:00
# Pacific time 2021-03-26T08:09:18-07:00

# for reference, local time and UTC:
now_local = datetime.now().astimezone()
now_UTC = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
print(f"Local time   {now_local.isoformat(timespec='seconds')}")
print(f"UTC          {now_UTC.isoformat(timespec='seconds')}")
# Local time   2021-03-26T16:09:18+01:00 # I'm on Europe/Berlin
# UTC          2021-03-26T15:09:18+00:00
```

Note: there's a [deprecation shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) for `pytz`.

***older versions of Python 3***: you can either use `zoneinfo` via the [backports](https://pypi.org/project/backports/) module or use [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) instead. dateutil's `tz.gettz` follows the same semantics as `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo`:

```
from dateutil.tz import gettz

now_Israel = datetime.now(gettz('Israel'))
now_Pacific = datetime.now(gettz('US/Pacific'))
print(f"Israeli time {now_Israel.isoformat(timespec='seconds')}")
print(f"Pacific time {now_Pacific.isoformat(timespec='seconds')}")
# Israeli time 2021-03-26T18:09:18+03:00
# Pacific time 2021-03-26T08:09:18-07:00
```

Comment: whats the problem to use`datetime.now(tz=gettz('US/Pacific'))`?

Comment: @LeonardRick that's perfectly fine! Actually I wanted to add this option as well, never took the time. Thanks for the reminder  ;-)

Answer (score 16):

One way, through the timezone setting of the C library, is

```
>>> cur=time.time()
>>> os.environ["TZ"]="US/Pacific"
>>> time.tzset()
>>> time.strftime("%T %Z", time.localtime(cur))
'03:09:51 PDT'
>>> os.environ["TZ"]="GMT"
>>> time.strftime("%T %Z", time.localtime(cur))
'10:09:51 GMT'
```

Comment: This only works in Unix according to the documentation. Not sure if that makes a difference here though.

Comment: I needed a solution that doesn't use pytz and only needs to run on Linux systems, so this is perfect

Comment: This one is perfectly working in AWS Lambda without pytz. Many thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The shortest ans of the question can be like:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
print(datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')))
```

This will print:

> 2019-06-20 12:48:56.862291+05:30

Comment: I dont want ot use external library. I want to use only native library. then how should I do?

Answer (score 9):

This script which makes use of the `pytz` and `datetime` modules is structured as requested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timezone

utc_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

PST = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
IST = pytz.timezone("Asia/Jerusalem")

print("UTC time     {}".format(utc_dt.isoformat()))
print("Local time   {}".format(utc_dt.astimezone().isoformat()))
print("Pacific time {}".format(utc_dt.astimezone(PST).isoformat()))
print("Israeli time {}".format(utc_dt.astimezone(IST).isoformat()))
```

It outputs the following:

```
$ ./timezones.py 
UTC time     2019-02-23T01:09:51.452247+00:00
Local time   2019-02-23T14:09:51.452247+13:00
Pacific time 2019-02-22T17:09:51.452247-08:00
Israeli time 2019-02-23T03:09:51.452247+02:00
```

Comment: Why would you use `pytz` when you already have `timezone`?

Answer (score 2):

This is my implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

def local_time(zone='Asia/Jerusalem'):
    other_zone = timezone(zone)
    other_zone_time = datetime.now(other_zone)
    return other_zone_time.strftime('%T')
```

Comment: not different than previous one. only function formatted and cleaner look.
I'll add it as a comment to it.
oh... I cannot comment.

Answer (score 0):

I need time info all time time, so I have this neat .py script on my server that lets me just select and deselect what time zones I want to display in order of east->west.

It prints like this:

```
Australia/Sydney    :   2016-02-09 03:52:29 AEDT+1100
Asia/Singapore      :   2016-02-09 00:52:29 SGT+0800
Asia/Hong_Kong      :   2016-02-09 00:52:29 HKT+0800
EET                 :   2016-02-08 18:52:29 EET+0200
CET                 :   2016-02-08 17:52:29 CET+0100     <- you are HERE
UTC                 :   2016-02-08 16:52:29 UTC+0000
Europe/London       :   2016-02-08 16:52:29 GMT+0000
America/New_York    :   2016-02-08 11:52:29 EST-0500
America/Los_Angeles :   2016-02-08 08:52:29 PST-0800
```

Here source code is one .py file on my github here: 
https://github.com/SpiRaiL/timezone
Or the direct file link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpiRaiL/timezone/master/timezone.py

In the file is a list like this:
Just put a 'p' in the places you want printed.
Put a 'h' for your own time zone if you want it specially marked.

```
(' ','America/Adak'),                               (' ','Africa/Abidjan'),                             (' ','Atlantic/Azores'),                            (' ','GB'),
(' ','America/Anchorage'),                          (' ','Africa/Accra'),                               (' ','Atlantic/Bermuda'),                           (' ','GB-Eire'),
(' ','America/Anguilla'),                           (' ','Africa/Addis_Ababa'),                         (' ','Atlantic/Canary'),                            (' ','GMT'),
(' ','America/Antigua'),                            (' ','Africa/Algiers'),                             (' ','Atlantic/Cape_Verde'),                        (' ','GMT+0'),
(' ','America/Araguaina'),                          (' ','Africa/Asmara'),                              (' ','Atlantic/Faeroe'),                            (' ','GMT-0'),
(' ','America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'),             (' ','Africa/Asmera'),                              (' ','Atlantic/Faroe'),                             (' ','GMT0'),
(' ','America/Argentina/Catamarca'),                (' ','Africa/Bamako'),                              (' ','Atlantic/Jan_Mayen'),                         (' ','Greenwich'),
(' ','America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia'),           (' ','Africa/Bangui'),                              (' ','Atlantic/Madeira'),                           (' ','HST'),
(' ','America/Argentina/Cordoba'),                  (' ','Africa/Banjul'),                              (' ','Atlantic/Reykjavik'),                         (' ','Hongkong'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can specify timezone by importing the modules `datetime` from `datetime` and `pytx`.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

tz_London = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)
print("London time:", datetime_London.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

tz_India = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
datetime_India = datetime.now(tz_India)
print("India time:", datetime_India.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Its 'Asia/Kolkata' not 'Asia/India', Get all available tzs: ```pytz.all_timezones```

Comment: @ShirishShukla Thanks for noticing. I have edited my answer to include Kolkata instead of India.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using `pandas` a lot in my code, and don't like importing extra libraries if I don't have to, so here's a solution I'm using that's simple and clean:

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.Timestamp.now('UTC') #pull UTC time
t_rounded = t.round('10min') #round to nearest 10 minutes
now_UTC_rounded = f"{t_rounded.hour:0>2d}{t_rounded.minute:0>2d}" #makes HH:MM format

t = pd.Timestamp.now(tz='US/Eastern') #pull Eastern (EDT or EST, as current) time
t_rounded = t.round('10min') #round to nearest 10 minutes
now_EAST_rounded = f"{t_rounded.hour:0>2d}{t_rounded.minute:0>2d}" #makes HH:MM format

print(f"The current UTC time is: {now_UTC_rounded} (rounded to the nearest 10 min)")
print(f"The current US/Eastern time is: {now_EAST_rounded} (rounded to the nearest 10 min)")
```

Outputs:

```
The current UTC time is: 1800 (rounded to the nearest 10 min)
The current US/Eastern time is: 1400 (rounded to the nearest 10 min)
```

(actual Eastern time was 14:03)
The rounding feature is nice because if you're trying to trigger something at a specific time, like on the hour, you can miss by 4 minutes on either side and still get a match.

Just showing off features - obviously you don't need to use the round if you don't want!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method which doesn't require importing pytz or any specific timezone libraries, you can do it in this way which only imports datetime. By using datetime to get the current UTC time then adding the timezone modifier, any desired timezone can be achieved.

For example, the timezone in New York is 4 hours behind UTC time, or UTC-04:00.
This means we can use this code to find the current time in New York:

```
import datetime

utc_time = datetime.datetime.utc(now)
tz_modifier = datetime.datetime.timedelta(hours=-4)
tz_time = utc_time + tz_modifier

print(tz_time)
```

To make this more "elegant" as was wanted, this method could be used:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

utc = datetime.utcnow()
print("China time {}".format(utc+timedelta(hours=8)))
print("Greece time {}".format(utc+timedelta(hours=3)))
print("Hawaii time {}".format(utc+timedelta(hours=-10)))
```

The downside to this method is that the actual UTC differences of the timezones must be known already.

Comment: This doesn't account for DST changes.