# Reading JSON file in Python and converting to PST zone

Tags: python, json, utc, pst

I have a JSON file that has the following.

```
["2014-05-01T00:04:35+00:00", "2014-05-01T01:07:15+00:00", "2014-03-02T00:09:54+00:00", "2014-03-02T00:10:34+00:00", "2014-03-02T00:10:22+00:00", "2014-05-03T00:10:55+00:00" ]
```

1. How do I read this?
2. Assuming that those dates are UTC, how do I convert it to PST zone?

Comment: Have you looked at the `json` module and the `datetime` module? You should check the docs first.

Comment: You really have *3* questions here; loading JSON is with the `json` module (look that up). Parsing the datetime strings means parsing the ISO 8601 format (see [How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/969285)), then translating from UTC to a different timezone is [need to convert UTC (aws ec2) to PST in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8809765)

Comment: I'll just close your question as a dupe of the last one; if you can narrow this down to *one* unique issue, we can consider reopening.