# Easy way to get date from UTC to PST in python 2.7.x

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = str(datetime.date.today())
>>> print today
2017-06-07
```

The machine is in UTC time. I would like to know if there is easy/simple way to get same kind of output for PST (without changing machine time zone).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809765/need-to-convert-utc-aws-ec2-to-pst-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
import pytz

def tz2ntz(date_obj, tz, ntz):

    # date_obj: datetime object
    # tz: old timezone
    # ntz: new timezone

    if isinstance(date_obj, datetime.date) and tz and ntz:
       date_obj = date_obj.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tz))
       return date_obj.astimezone(pytz.timezone(ntz))
    return False

print tz2ntz(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), 'UTC', 'US/Pacific')
```