# Python timezone using only modules available in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7

I'm trying run this code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990420/196032).

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    date_format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
    date = datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
    print('Current date & time is:', date.strftime(date_format))

    date = date.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))

    print('Local date & time is  :', date.strftime(date_format))
```

I am running on AWS Lambda. I am getting this error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pytz'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

How can I fix this, using only imports available in AWS Lambda? I want to keep the code very minimalistic so that it can be copy-pasted directly into the AWS Console, without having to add instructions on how to setup packages etc.

Comment: This answer to another question may be helpful using dateutil.tz: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231362/11234542

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have access to `pytz` in AWS Lambda, you can use `python-dateutil`.
In that case you can do:

```
import datetime
import dateutil

date_format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z'

IST = dateutil.tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')
print('Current date & time is : ',datetime.datetime.now(tz=IST).strftime(date_format))

or

eastern = dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern')
print('Current date & time is : ',datetime.datetime.now(tz=eastern).strftime(date_format))
```

Here's the preview:
[image: preview]