# Converting two date formats to one in a dataframe column in Python

Tags: python

I have a excel sheet, which i am reading using Python.
There's a date column, where the data is in below format:

```
2017/10/02 13:51:39 BST
2017/11/08 19:55:11 GMT
```

I need to convert the data to GMT format itself.
Any ways to do so?

Comment: What is BST here?

Comment: You need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` if need convert `date` column.

Comment: Looks like it is British Summer Time.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855586/in-python-how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-in-a-specific-local-time-not-my-local-to

Comment: Yes, BST is british summer time which is 1 hour ahead of GMT.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dict` with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017/10/02 13:51:39 BST', '2017/11/08 19:55:11 GMT']})


d = {'BST':'+0100', 'GMT':'+0000'}
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].replace(d, regex=True))
print (df)

                 date
0 2017-10-02 12:51:39
1 2017-11-08 19:55:11
```