# Only some timezones working in datetime module for python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a time (including timezone) to just a time with everything in UTC. When i have the timezone GMT it works fine, but soon as i use PDT or PST i get an error.
Am i going about this the right way or is there a better way to do this?

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("10:54:02 PM GMT", "%I:%M:%S %p %Z").strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'22:54:02'
```

I've seen pytz might be helpful to me but not sure how to use it within the date string.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/python-display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* need to parse PST/PDT, you don't need `pytz`, as they are, by definition, always 8/7 hours away from UTC. You can simply interpret the data as a naive datetime (i.e.: exclude the timezone from the string you pass into `strptime`), then subtract 7 or 8 hours, depending on the timezone.

If you need to parse more timezones, or simply want to have the code ready for it, the link `sk11` mentioned should be enough to get you started.