# How to get daylight-saving-aware GMT

Tags: python, django, datetime, time, timezone

Using Python/Django 1.5.4, I am trying to find a way of getting the current time in London, UK.

It seems to be surprisingly complicated to do so.

Obviously there is the time.time(), datetime.now(), datetime.utcnow(), but these methods return the server time.

This is a problem because the server may not be in the UK and the above methods don't take daylight saving into account.

Is there a simple, straightforward way of doing this without excessive imports and third-party apps?

Comment: You should definitely not be using Django 1.5. It has been unsupported for quite some time and is probably subject to lots of security issues. Upgrade to 1.8 at a minimum.

Comment: GMT doesn't have DST. Did you mean GMT vs. BST?

Comment: However the answer to your question is almost certainly found in the comprehensive [documentation on timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/).

Comment: Try and check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/python-display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, Django 1.5... tell me about it..! In the process of migrating a large project to a more recent version.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using time.time(), datetime.now(), datetime.utcnow(), when in django use `from django.utils import timezone and use timezone.now`. This is specifically designed to handle such scenarios in django. For further reading check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing

Comment: @AliSkinner: you should set `USE_TZ=True` (it is set if `settings.py` is generated by  `django-admin startproject`) so that `timezone.now()` would return a timezone-aware datetime object (in UTC timezone that may be different from London time). Set `TIME_ZONE=Europe/London` so that London time would be the default while rendering time in templates (use `.activate()` to change a per request current time zone).

Comment: @AliSkinner if you think this is the best approach to your issue, please accept the answer so others can be benefited from the same. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

To get the current time in London, UK:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

print(datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London')))
```

It works correctly even during DST transitions when the local time may be ambiguous.

In `django`, set [`USE_TZ=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) and use [`timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) to get the current time in UTC as an aware datetime object. It is rendered in templates using the current time zone that you could set using [`.activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) otherwise the default time zone is used that is defined by [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#time-zone).