# Substract current time to -GMT in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a time which is 13:11:06 and i want to -GMT (i.e -0530). I can minus it by simply doing -5 by splitting the string taking the first digit (convert to int) and then minus it and then re-join. But then i get it in a format which is 8:11:06 which is not right as it should be 08:11:06, secondly its a lengthy process. Is there a easy way to get my time in -GMT format (08:11:06)

This is what i did to get -GMT time after getting the datetime

```
timesplithour = int(timesplit[1]) + -5
timesplitminute = timesplit[2]
timesplitseconds = timesplit[3]
print timesplithour
print timesplitminute
print timesplitseconds
print timesplithour + ":" + timesplitminute + ":" + timesplitseconds
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? please include what you have tried in here

Comment: What type is the time: a) a string, b) a datetime, c) a timezone aware datetime, d) something else?

Comment: What is timesplithour? is that a string? datetime? please include the initialization of the variables.

Comment: If you want to get the current time in the given timezone then avoid string operations, get the time directly e.g.: [`datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta'))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5096669/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Python's [`datatime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#module-datetime) library to help you as follows:

```
import datetime

my_time = "13:11:06"
new_time = datetime.datetime.strptime("2016 " + my_time, "%Y %H:%M:%S") - datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
print new_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

This would print:

```
 07:41:06
```

First it converts your string into a `datetime` object. It then creates a `timedelta` object allowing you to subtract 5 hours 30 minutes from the datetime object. Finally it uses `strftime` to format the resulting datetime into a string in the same format.

Comment: Thanks @Martiin. This is exactly why i need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.strptime('13:11:06', '%H:%M:%S')
time_gmt = (dt - timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)).time()

print(time_gmt.hour)
print(time_gmt.minute)
print(time_gmt.second)
s = time_gmt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(s)
```

**Output**

```
7
41
6
07:41:06
```

Note that this subtracts 5 hours and 30 minutes as initially mentioned in the question. If you really only want to subtract 5 hours, use `timedelta(hours=5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datetimes timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
print datetime.datetime.today()
>>> datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 3, 10, 45, 6, 270711)
print datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
>>> datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 10, 45, 8, 559073)
```

This way you can subtract easily

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the time is a datetime instance

```
import datetime as dt
t = datetime(2015,12,31,13,11,06)
#t.time() # gives time object. ie no date information

offset = dt.timedelta(hours=5,minutes=30) # or hours=5.5

t -= offset    

t.strftime(("%H:%M:%S") # output as your desired string
#'18:41:06'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object is datetime and you don't care about DST, the simplest thing you can do is,

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: curr = datetime.now()

In [3]: curr
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 3, 9, 57, 31, 302231)

In [4]: curr.utcnow()
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 3, 8, 57, 57, 286956)
```