# Unix timestamp to iso 8601 time format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, iso8601

> When I convert unix time 1463288494 to isoformat i get 2016-05-14T22:01:34. How can I get the output including the -07:00. In this format 2016-05-14T22:01:34-07:00

```
from datetime import datetime
t =  int("1463288494")
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(t).isoformat())
```

Comment: You need to attach a `tzinfo` class to your `datetime` but I don't know if that's sufficient.

Comment: For anyone that needs zulu time you can use: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t).isoformat() + 'Z'`.

Answer (score 23):

You can pass a `tzinfo` instance representing your timezone offset to `fromtimestamp()`. The problem then is how to get the `tzinfo` object. The easiest way is to use the [`pytz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) module which provides a `tzinfo` compatible object:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1463288494, tz).isoformat())

#2016-05-14T22:01:34-07:00
```

Comment: With Python 3.9+, you can use the standard library 's [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module to get the timezone object.

Comment: @FObersteiner how to do that?

Comment: @AbelCallejo like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418) for example