# Converting Python datetime from UTC to PST

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Using Python, I have a datetime object with the value (for example)

```
datetime(2021, 12, 28, 22, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

This prints as

```
2021-12-28 22:31:00+00:00
```

How do I display that in US/Pacific?

I've seen references that use `import pytz` but I don't have that library available.

**ANSWER**:
Even though it isn't the checked answer, I like the response by @jfs

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def utc_to_local(utc_dt):
    return utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)
```

Output:

```
orig: 2021-12-28 22:31:00+00:00
after utc_to_local: 2021-12-28 14:31:00-08:00
```

At this time I am in PST and the offset from UTC is 8 hours

Comment: more duplicates [Convert UTC datetime to Pacific datetime in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49671138/10197418), [need to convert UTC (aws ec2) to PST in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809765/10197418)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 3.9+ you can use the built-in [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html):

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime(2021, 12, 28, 22, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())
date = date.astimezone(ZoneInfo('US/Pacific'))
```

```text
2021-12-28 14:31:00-08:00
```

Comment: Why not use `ZoneInfo('UTC')` and save an import?