# How can I specify a timezone on python's datetime functions?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

How can I specify a timezone like "Amazon Time" (UTC -4) in a `datetime` function?

Every reference that I search mentions the creation of a `tzinfo` class, but that seems too much hurdle for a simple problem. Is there a simpler way to do it?

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Why can't I do something like this?
datetime.utcnow(offset=-4)
```

Comment: @deceze: You redirected this duplicate to another duplicate.. [See: here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a timezone to the `now` function:

```
import datetime
import pytz

datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Manaus'))

# => datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 4, 16, 38, 41, 584695, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Manaus' AMT-1 day, 20:00:00 STD>)
```

I got the timezone name [from this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).