# How to get the time in specific time as time.time()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am trying to set the specific time and display as second like time.time() does. Let's say I want to display exact time 2019/1/1 12:00 AM.

The code would be

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0).timestamp()
```

But, if I wanted to make sure it is in specific time zone (like AST, EST).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Question answered here: [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone)

Here is the essential code from one of the answers:

```html
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone    

south_africa = timezone('Africa/Johannesburg')
sa_time = datetime.now(south_africa)
print sa_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
```