# How to determine the appropriate the timezone to apply for historical dates in a give region in python3

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, utc

I'm using python3 on Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a trove of files with naive datetime strings in them, dating back more than 20 years. I know that all of these datetimes are in the Pacific Timezone. I would like to convert them all to UTC datetimes.

However, whether they are relative to PDT or PST is a bigger question. Since when PDT/PST changes has changed over the last 20 years, it's not just a matter of doing a simple date/month threshold to figure out whether to apply the pdt or pst timezone. Is there an elegant way to make this determination and apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note upfront, for **Python 3.9+: use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)** from the standard library, no need anymore for a third party library. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418).

---

Here's what you can to do set the timezone and convert to UTC. [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will take DST changes from the [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

datestrings = ['1991-04-06T00:00:00', # PST
               '1991-04-07T04:00:00', # PDT
               '1999-10-30T00:00:00', # PDT
               '1999-10-31T02:01:00', # PST
               '2012-03-11T00:00:00', # PST
               '2012-03-11T02:00:00'] # PDT

# to naive datetime objects
dateobj = [datetime.fromisoformat(s) for s in datestrings]

# set timezone:
tz_pacific = dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Pacific')
dtaware = [d.replace(tzinfo=tz_pacific) for d in dateobj] 
# with pytz use localize() instead of replace

# check if has DST:
# for d in dtaware: print(d.dst())
# 0:00:00
# 1:00:00
# 1:00:00
# 0:00:00
# 0:00:00
# 1:00:00

# convert to UTC:
dtutc = [d.astimezone(dateutil.tz.UTC) for d in dtaware]

# check output
# for d in dtutc: print(d.isoformat())
# 1991-04-06T08:00:00+00:00
# 1991-04-07T11:00:00+00:00
# 1999-10-30T07:00:00+00:00
# 1999-10-31T10:01:00+00:00
# 2012-03-11T08:00:00+00:00
# 2012-03-11T09:00:00+00:00
```

Now if you'd like to be absolutely sure that DST (PDT vs. PST) is set correctly, you'd have to setup test cases and verify against IANA I guess...

Comment: Needs an `import dateutil.tz` as well

Comment: @TravisGriggs: I import the whole package with `import dateutil` - you are right, `dateutil.tz` would suffice