# Python: How can i show current time of timezone IST irrespective of my current system time

Tags: python

i tried using import datetime and several other but when i change my System time it show according to my current system time instead actual time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone)

Comment: nope that doesn't solve my question, in this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone] 
it only show time of different time zone which work according to your system time if i alter the system it show different time

Comment: Please clarify your problem and question with more details. If you don't want to use your local system time (because why exactly?) then your other option is to query a network service (is that what you want to do?). If so then probably the first choice would be querying a [Network Time Protocol (NTP) server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) either by using the [ntplib library](https://pypi.org/project/ntplib/) or by coding it yourself. Otherwise, you can also query an online service like the [World Time API](https://worldtimeapi.org) which offers a JSON and plaintext API.

Comment: i did write clearly i want to show time irrespective of my system time,, idk what else do i write to clarify you!

Comment: @IvoMori thanks i'll try NTP and world time API

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pytz` to do so:

```
import datetime
import pytz
date = datetime.datetime.now()
timezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
date_ist = timezone.localize(date)
```

Comment: what d in  timezone.localize(d) denote ?

is it supposed to be date(from date = datetime.datetime.now() )?

Comment: You can also do it the other way around, pass the timezone into the `now()` function, like this: `ist = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"); date_ist = datetime.datetime.now(ist)`

Comment: sorry but this give me wrong time, since i have alter my system time and i have clearly said that i want time irrespective of my system time

Answer (score 0):

NTP servers are what this is for. You need a clock to reliably get time data. Usually that's the system clock. But NTP is good when you want your code to be independent of that.

[ntplib](https://pypi.org/project/ntplib/) is a library that makes querying these easy

Comment: is there any way without using external library?