# Datetime library timezone

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert following string into datetime format

```
work_date="Sun Aug 23 20:16:44 IST 2020"
dt_new=datetime.datetime.strptime(work_date,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
print(dt_new)
```

But I am always getting timedata does not match the format. I tried replacing IST with GMT, it works. Also tried replacing IST with 'Asia/Kolkata' but it still doesn't work.
I wanted to know if there is some way to register IST under %Z format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone)

Answer (score 1):

`strptime` only accepts certain values for `%Z`:

1. any value in `time.tzname` for your machine's locale
2. the hard-coded values `UTC` and `GMT`

You could use UTC and convert it by [`pytz`](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/) third library:

```py
import datetime
import pytz

work_date = "Sun Aug 23 20:16:44 UTC 2020"
dt_new = datetime.datetime.strptime(work_date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
dt_new = dt_new.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"))
print(dt_new)
```

Update: Also you can use `dateutil` module:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.tz import gettz
tzinfos = {"IST": gettz("Asia/Kolkata")}
print(parse("Sun Aug 23 20:16:44 IST 2020", tzinfos=tzinfos))
```