# How to get current time in india in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timestamp, timezone

How would I get the current timestamp in python of India?

I tried `time.ctime()` and `datetime.utcnow()` also `datetime.now()`
but they all return a different time than here it is in india.

The codes above return the time that not match the current time on my computer. and the time in my computer is definitely correct.

Comment: datetime.now() will return the correct time if your computer's date/time is set correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone)

Comment: save yourself some trouble and skip using pytz, see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```py
from pytz import timezone 
from datetime import datetime

ind_time = datetime.now(timezone("Asia/Kolkata")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(ind_time)
>>> "2020-08-28 11:56:37.010822"
```

Comment: this is actually better than the answer you accepted... see my comment there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use timedelta object in datetime module:

since the Indian Standard Time (IST) is 5.5 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), we can shift the UTC time to 5hrs and 30 mins.

```
import datetime as dt

dt_India_naive = dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
dt_India_aware = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone(dt.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)))

dt_UTC_naive = dt.datetime.utcnow()
dt_UTC_aware = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc)

max_len = len(max(['UTC Time', 'Indian Time'], key=len))

print(f"{'UTC Time'   :<{max_len}} - {dt_UTC_aware:%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S}")
print(f"{'Indian Time':<{max_len}} - {dt_India_aware:%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S}")

# Both offset-naive and offset-aware will provide same results in this sitatuiion
```

Result:-

```
UTC Time    - 20-Feb-23 03:29:12
Indian Time - 20-Feb-23 08:59:12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with pytz:

```
import datetime,pytz

dtobj1=datetime.datetime.utcnow()   #utcnow class method
print(dtobj1)

dtobj3=dtobj1.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) #replace method


#print(pytz.all_timezones) => To see all timezones
dtobj_india=dtobj3.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")) #astimezone method
print(dtobj_india)
```

result:

```
2020-08-28 06:01:13.833290
2020-08-28 11:31:13.833290+05:30
```

Comment: utcnow() can be pretty misleading, -> [stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html)