# How can you get the unix epoch timestamp in seconds from a given date and time in a given city?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

I am trying to get the corresponding Epoch Unix timestamp (in seconds) for the following New York date and time:

```
2020-09-25 09:30 New York Time.
```

Which according to https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1601040600&tz=America%2FNew_York correponds to:

```
Conversion results (1601040600)
1601040600 converts to Friday September 25, 2020 09:30:00 (am) in time zone America/New York (EDT)
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
import datetime
import pytz
​
et = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
​
mydt = datetime.datetime(2020,9,25,9,30,0,0,et)

​myepoch = int(mydt.timestamp())
​
print('2020-09-25 09:30 ET Epoch: ', myepoch)
​    ​
>>> OUTPUT
2020-09-25 09:30 ET Epoch:  1601043960
​
```

So it gives `1601043960` instead of `1601040600`. Why and what shall be done to get the right value?

Note the solution shall work for any date, so it must automatically take care of EST/EDT daylight saving.

Comment: if you have access to a geographic database (e.g. OSM/Nominatim), you could even look up the coordinates of the city with [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), get the time zone for that coordinates using [timezonefinder](https://github.com/MrMinimal64/timezonefinder) and *then* obtain the local time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the solution is this one:

```py
import datetime
import pytz
​
et = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
​
mydt = et.localize(datetime.datetime(2020,9,25,9,30,0,0))

​myepoch = int(mydt.timestamp())
​
print('2020-09-25 09:30 ET Epoch: ', myepoch)
​    ​
>>> OUTPUT
2020-09-25 09:30 ET Epoch:  1601040600
```

Comment: see [deprecation of pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) and [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418)

Comment: oh and check out [the fastest footgun in the west](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) as to *why* you get invalid timestamps if you don't localize (LMT...) ;-)