# Datetime + PyTZ + Dailight savings time is off

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, pytz

I am currently having an issue with correct conversion of dates
The `localhost` is running `CET`, when I create a `UTC` `datetime` and convert it to `PST` time it will return the default -8h (respective to UTC). This is generally true but right now there is the dailight savings offset UTC -> PST = -7 . Do I have to consider a special flag during the tz conversion?

```
In [3]: pytz.__version__                                                                                    
Out[3]: '2019.3'

In [5]: import datetime                                                                                     

In [6]: datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))                         
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 23, 8, 53, 15, 833429, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)

In [7]: !date                                                                                               
Tue 23 Mar 2021 05:53:20 PM CET
```

Code above should return 9AM , not 8AM.

Comment: `utcnow()` returns naive datetime, use `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)` instead. Side-note #1: your pytz version is outdated, the current one is 2021.1. Side-note #2: since Python 3.9, there's zoneinfo, which I think is a bit more convenient than pytz ([exemplary usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418)).

Comment: Thanks. `datetime.timezone.utc` did the trick. Unfortunately I might not have control about the pytz version. Thanks for the `zoneinfo` pointer :)

Comment: actually, you can simplify to e.g. `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))` to get current time in a certain time zone.  But the `utcnow` thing explains why this went wrong in the first place ;-)

Comment: Thank you all. Bit puzzled why `utcnow` is naive. I knew `now` was so its clashing in my head. Something to memorize :)

Comment: yeah, `utcnow` is weird, there's even [a blog post about it](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html). As long as you supply a time zone to `now`, it returns aware datetime (in that time zone).