# two different second with the same date by datetime library

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

recently I discover problem in my database. 3rd party pass the data as a second and I convert this with python to date and store it to DB. But two different Seconds saved as one date.
how can I avoid this?
My code:

```
import datetime

A = datetime.fromtimestamp(1600194600).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print('A: ' , A)

B = datetime.fromtimestamp(1600198200).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print('B: ' , B)
```

And the Result is:

```
A:  2020-09-15 23:00:00
B:  2020-09-15 23:00:00
```

Comment: I think your import should be `from datetime import datetime`. To which time zone is the machine set to that you use to run this code on? I mean, in which time zone do you wish to display the date?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Almost surely related to different timezone where code A and code B runs.

Comment: @MrFuppes , I change to `from datetime import datetime` but the problem is exist. But your right. the source data time zone is UTC and my machine is +3:30

Comment: @wim , A and B have the same Source and they are correct in source application, and both run on my PC

Comment: Hm, did you have a DST change on 2020-9-15 to 2020-9-16? Would be an unusual date but that's the only thing I can think of right now that would explain the duplicate date.

Comment: No, the DTS change on 2020-09-20. anyway it's ok to me to store data with UTC timezone in DB (exactly like source date). is it possible?

Comment: Sure, added an answer. You might also be interested in having a look at [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398674/10197418).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly convert to UTC ([aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects)) by setting the `tz` argument when calling [datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp). Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
# Unix time / seconds since the epoch refers to UTC:
A = datetime.fromtimestamp(1600194600, tz=timezone.utc)
B = datetime.fromtimestamp(1600198200, tz=timezone.utc)

print(A.isoformat(' '))
print(B.isoformat(' '))

>>> 2020-09-15 18:30:00+00:00
>>> 2020-09-15 19:30:00+00:00
```

Now you can convert to a certain time zone, e.g.

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+, for older versions use e.g. backports.zoneinfo
zone = ZoneInfo('Asia/Tehran')

A = A.astimezone(zone)
B = B.astimezone(zone)

print(A.isoformat(' '), str(A.tzinfo))
print(B.isoformat(' '), str(B.tzinfo))

>>> 2020-09-15 23:00:00+04:30 Asia/Tehran
>>> 2020-09-16 00:00:00+04:30 Asia/Tehran
```