# How can I convert from UTC time to local time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, timezone

So, I want to convert UTC date time `2021-08-05 10:03:24.585Z` to Indian date time how to convert it?

What I tried is

```
from datetime import datetime

from pytz import timezone

st = "2021-08-05 10:03:24.585Z"

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(st, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ')

local_tz = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
start_date = local_tz.localize(datetime_object)
print(start_date.replace(tzinfo=local_tz))
```

But Still the output is not with the timezone I have mentioned how can I convert the time and print the time from the time.

Output:

```
2021-08-05 10:03:24.585000+05:21
```

Comment: @deceze When I tried to print just `start_date` the output is `2021-08-05 10:03:24.585000+05:30`

Comment: see e.g. [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398674/10197418) and [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418)

Comment: @MrFuppes when I used `astimezone()` it says can't convert naive datetime. I'm a newbie to this you could you spare some of your time and help me by explaining it?

Comment: yup, the problem is the `Z` in your parsing directive. it basically makes `strptime` ignore the fact that "Z" should be parsed to *aware* datetime, with aware meaning the datetime object "knows" that it belongs in a certain time zone, UTC in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sth like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')

utc = datetime.strptime('2011-01-21 02:37:21', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)

central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
```

Comment: How does one programatically get the correct local timezone?

Comment: @JonathanHartley you'll have to use a third party library; [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal)

Answer (score 4):

parse the date/time string to UTC datetime correctly and use [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) instead of `replace` to *convert* to a certain time zone (option for newer Python version (3.9+) in comments):

```
from datetime import datetime
# from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from dateutil.tz import gettz

st = "2021-08-05 10:03:24.585Z"
zone = "Asia/Kolkata"

# dtUTC = datetime.fromisoformat(st.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
dtUTC = datetime.strptime(st, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

# dtZone = dtUTC.astimezone(ZoneInfo(zone))
dtZone = dtUTC.astimezone(gettz(zone))

print(dtZone.isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
# 2021-08-05T15:33:24+05:30
```

If you just need local time, i.e. your machine's setting, you can use `astimezone(None)` as well.

Comment: this causes this error `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'`

Comment: @hamere: which Python version are you using?

Comment: I use python 3.7 version

Comment: @hamere sounds like "time to upgrade" ^^ actually this feature was introduced with Python 3.7 so it *should* work... you can try `datetime.strptime(st, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')` instead.

Comment: @hamere  check if any other versions installed

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.10.8

```
from datetime import datetime
st = "2021-08-05 10:03:24.585Z"
dtUTC = datetime.fromisoformat(st[:-1]+'+00:00')
dtUTC = dtUTC.astimezone()
print(dtUTC.isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
# 2021-08-05T15:33:24+05:30
```

Comment: cannot reproduce that this works correctly. my machine is set to UTC+2 so this code gives `2021-08-05T10:03:24+02:00` - which is wrong since the input should be UTC, not UTC+2.