# How do i get date and time in my local timezone in python?

Tags: python, datetime, operating-system, timezone

I have tried a lot but cannot find a way to get current date time in my local timezone in python. I don't want to specify the timezone. I just want to get the local timezone where the app is operating.

`datetime.datetime.now()`

gets the UTC datetime. i have tried:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
datetime.datetime.now(get_localzone)
```

but it is of no use.

`get_localzone()` returns UTC i don't know why.
`datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo` also returns UTC.

I have also found that my VS code is also in UTC timezone but my system is in local timezone. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get local time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735250/how-to-get-local-time-in-python)

Comment: What's your Python environment configuration when you run the code ? Are you running in WSL on Windows for example ?

Comment: @Schorsch thankyou but no it doesnot answer my question.

Comment: @FObersteiner i am running linux mint and created a virtual env for django

Answer (score 1):

You get local time with python3:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

local_t = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat()
print(local_t)

print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().tzinfo)
```

Output:

```
2023-09-14T13:17:00.611396+02:00
CEST
```

Comment: it still returns time in UTC and ```.tzinfo``` prints UTC in it