# Convert a date with UTC timezone offset to corresponding local timezone format

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, pytz

I have a string date which already contains an appropriate time zone offset -08:00 and I can convert it into a datetime variable but with UTC time zone format:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

str_date = '2020-01-01T00:00:00-08:00'#
specific_date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"

my_date = datetime.fromisoformat(str_date)
print(my_date.strftime(specific_date_format))

_____________________________________________
Output
>> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC-08:00
```

Format I need is

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00 PST
```

Not sure how to convert UTC-08:00 into PST.

Tried with pytz and saw suggestions to replace time zone with predefined 'America/Los_Angeles', but I need the code to detect that the hour offset UTC-08:00 corresponds to 'America/Los_Angeles' time zone and convert it as such.

Comment: which python version? do you *have* have to use pytz?

Comment: Version: Python 3.8.8 & pytz would be ideal, but other standard python libraries would work as well. Thanks in advance, @MrFuppes!

Comment: Note that UTC offsets can correspond to multiple time zones, so an unambiguous mapping of UTC offset to time zone is not possible in general. You'll have to *define* the mapping, e.g. 8 hours behind UTC corresponds to America/LA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your input already contains a UTC offset, you can [parse the iso-format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) to aware datetime (tzinfo set) and use [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) to set the correct time zone. Using pytz:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone # Python 3.9: zoneinfo (standard lib)

str_date = '2020-01-01T00:00:00-08:00'

# to datetime
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(str_date)

# to tz
dt_tz = dt.astimezone(timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))

print(dt_tz)
# 2020-01-01 00:00:00-08:00
print(repr(dt_tz))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
print(dt_tz.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"))
# Wed, 01 Jan 2020 00:00:00 PST
```

See also: [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398674/10197418) - e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418) for a Python 3.9/zoneinfo example.