# Is there a clean way to get the datetime module in python to accurately display other timezones?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am working on a crypto bot and using the datetime module to send price updates via SMS.

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime.now()
```

The datetime module is in military time (24 hour clock) and 7 hours ahead of my local time (PST), and I convert it by subtracting 7 from the time:

```
pst = abs(int(current_time.hour) - 7)
```

If the time is between 1 AM - 11 AM PST this works perfectly.
If the time is between 12 PM - 4 PM, I do:

```
if pst > 12 or pst == 0:
    pst_time = abs(pst) - 12
```

5 PM - 12 AM PST doesn't work as `current_time` = resets 0 to 7 and are < 12 which won't trigger the if statement.

Any advice on how to cleanly fix this without creating a huge table of numbers and setting them to a specific hour?

Comment: why don't you use another module, like `pytz` or `zoneinfo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.9+, you can use the builtin [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module:

```
>>> from zoneinfo import available_timezones
>>> available_timezones()
```

If you see an empty `set()` as the output, you might need to install `tzdata` package:

```
pip install tzdata
```

Sample usage with `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

PST = ZoneInfo('US/Pacific')

dt = datetime(2020, 10, 31, 12, tzinfo=PST)
print(dt)  # 2020-10-31 12:00:00-07:00
```