# How can I find the day of the week *adjusted for a timezone* using datetime (Python)?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

The `datetime` module allows for returning an integer representation of the weekday with:

```
weekday = dt.date.today().weekday()
```

However, this seems to be in UTC timezone (the default timezone for `datetime`). How can I convert this weekday integer to be adjusted for a timezone such as GMT? What I am looking for is something like the following using the `pytz` module:

```
weekday = dt.date.today().astimezone(pytz.gmt).weekday()
```

Is there an easy method of doing this so that the day reporting is accurate based on the shift in hours from the timezone? Thanks for any/all information.

Comment: try this link.
https://pynative.com/python-timezone/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone) - Python 3.9+ [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418)

Comment: Btw. naive datetime represents *local time* in Python, i.e. in the time zone of the machine you run the script on. That might just happen to be UTC, but it doesn't have to. GMT ("Europe/London" tz) has zero UTC offset, so that might trick you into thinking it's UTC.