# Timezone converter using python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have created a timezone converter using python using libraries like pytz and datetime

Is there a way to make it without using any libraries

Comment: Yes it is. (the answer is as elaborate as the question :D )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone)

Comment: You **do not want to roll your own datetime lib**, see "*Falsehoods programmers believe about time*" [#1](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) and [#2](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time). But you can avoid the deprecated `pytz`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418) to the linked dupe.