# Why is python's datetime conversion wrong in one direction?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I am trying to convert a timezone aware `datetime.datetime` object to UTC and make it naive. For the conversion, I use the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt: datetime = datetime(2023, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam"))
print(pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam").utcoffset(dt=datetime.now()))
print(dt)
print(dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone("UTC")))
```

This outputs the following:

```
1:00:00
2023-01-02 12:00:00+00:18
2023-01-02 11:42:00+00:00
```

For some reason, the time offset ends up being only 18 minutes instead on one hour. If I try to accomplish the opposite (from UTC to Europe/Amsterdam) it does work correctly:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt: datetime = datetime(2023, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("UTC"))
print(dt)
print(dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")))
```

Output (just as expected):

```
1:00:00
2023-01-02 12:00:00+00:00
2023-01-02 13:00:00+01:00
```

Could anybody tell me why this is happening and how I could fix it? Or is there even a simpler method to convert to UTC and make the datetime naive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [pytz documentation](https://pytz.sourceforge.net):

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

Instead you should use `localize()` function. This will work fine:

```python
pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam").localize(datetime(2023, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0))
```

Update: as mentioned in the comment, pytz is deprecated, use `zoneinfo`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398674/display-the-time-in-a-different-time-zone/63628816#63628816).

Comment: `pytz` is deprecated; the standard library has `zoneinfo` since Python 3.9. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418).