# Convert Datetime Objects as per Time zones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

I have tried two different scenarios:

1. I fetched Current Datetime of `UTC` and `Europe/Paris` and then I just converted in string which shows `02 hours` of gap which is correct.

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import pytz
from dateutil import tz

current_utc = datetime.utcnow()
current_europe = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))

current_utc_str = datetime.strftime(current_utc, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
current_europe_str = datetime.strftime(current_europe, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

print('current_utc',current_utc_str)
print('current_europe',current_europe_str)
```

results:

```
current_utc 2023-03-30 07:01
current_europe 2023-03-30 09:01
```

2. I created a custom UTC datetime object and then converted it to Europe/Paris timezone and here are the results with the Gap of `01 Hour`.

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import pytz
from dateutil import tz

utc = datetime(2023, 3, 21, 23, 45).replace(tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)
utc_str = datetime.strftime(utc, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print("utc_str", utc_str)

from_zone = tz.gettz("UTC")
to_zone = tz.gettz('Europe/Paris')
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
new_time = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
new_time_str = datetime.strftime(new_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print("new_time_str", new_time_str)
```

results:

```
utc_str 2023-03-21 23:45
new_time_str 2023-03-22 00:45
```

What is the reason behind this `01 hour of variation` while fetching current and creating custom datetime?

**Edit**
How can we handle Daylight Saving Time (DST) for custom created Datetime objects?

I think [Display the time in a different time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398674/16250404) this doesn't answer about handling Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Comment: concerning DST transitions: you don't handle those yourself, they are handled by the datetime + timezone libraries. The latter have to implement the rules of the [IANA tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which include DST transitions.