# Getting NonExistentTimeError in pytz

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

With this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytz

timestamp = pd.Timestamp('2023-04-30 02:20:28.594000')
timezone = pytz.timezone('Africa/Casablanca')


print(
    timestamp.tz_localize(timezone, ambiguous=True)
)
```

I'm getting `NonExistentTimeError: 2023-04-30 02:20:28.594000`.

Why is this time nonexistent? I happen to have local Casablanca data with that time.

Comment: Works for me, pasted literally from your code. Is there a daylight savings transition that day? Such that the time jumps from 02:00 to 03:00?

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Is your pytz version up-to-date? Note that pytz has been deprecated for a while now; in new projects consider using [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). [Usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, it was predicted that Morocco (`Africa/Casablanca`) would have its "spring-forward" transition on April 30th, 2023.  This was corrected in TZDB version 2023a.

From [the release announcement](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2023-March/000077.html):

> ```
> Changes to future timestamps
>
> In 2023 Morocco's spring-forward transition after Ramadan
> will occur April 23, not April 30.  (Thanks to Milamber.)
> Adjust predictions for future years accordingly.  This affects
> predictions for 2023, 2031, 2038, and later years.
> ```

The releases for pytz follow the tzdb releases.  Update to the current release of pytz and the transition date should be adjusted accordingly.

Also, note that pytz has been deprecated for a while now.  In new projects consider using [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) instead.  Note that zoneinfo will use the time zone data present on the operating system if present (i.e., Linux, MacOS, etc.), or data from the [tzdata](https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/#description) package in other cases (Windows, embedded systems, etc.).  In either case, be sure you are using the latest version.

Comment: Also note, the government made its announcement on March 1st - far too little notice for a change happening in April, IMHO.  See https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2023-March/032598.html and also https://codeofmatt.com/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/