# Time Zones and Daylight Savings Time on restricted server

Tags: bash, date, timezone

I'm running a bash script on a Github runner that I have no control over. In it, I need to compare timestamps to make certain that the current time is within an accepted timeframe.

I get start and end timestamps with date, and the script should only continue if the current date/time is within those timestamps.

But the server is so locked down that I cannot use `TZ=America/Chicago date` - it refuses to let me update TZ or anything else that I was able to find to temporarily set a time zone. I read that the time zone can be set to read-only, so that would be my guess.

What finally worked was this:

```
now=$(date '+%s' -d "now CST")
startdate=$(date '+%s' -d "$startraw CST")
finishdate=$(date '+%s' -d "$finishraw CST")

if [ $now -ge $startdate ] && [ $now -lt $finishdate ]; then
  echo "Current time is allowed"
else
  echo "ERROR - current time is not allowed"
fi
```

`$startraw` and `$finishraw` are in this format: `03/21/2024 08:00:00`.

I tried inserting `America/Chicago` instead of `CST` but that could not be parsed, so I used `CST`.

Now I had a UTC timestamp that I could compare correctly - until Daylight Savings hit when the current time no longer fit into the start and end time values even when it should.

So I found that there is `CDT` which is CST with daylight savings time included (if I understood it correctly).

Except now my results are even more off...

I just ran some test code:

```
now1=$(date '+%s' -d "now CST")
now2=$(date '+%s' -d "now CDT")

echo "Human readable times:"
echo "Now CST: $(date -d @$now1)"
echo "Now CDT: $(date -d @$now2)"
```

It is currently 8:11am CST [edit: CST in colloquial terms, not in computer terms]. This should be 1:11pm UTC according to Google.

The output when I convert the timestamp back into human readable:

```
Now CST: Thu Mar 21 19:11:44 UTC 2024
Now CDT: Thu Mar 21 18:11:44 UTC 2024
```

So that is 7pm and 6pm instead of the expected 1pm.

The server should be set to use UTC since my test code resulted in an output with "UTC" in it.

I guess it is possible that the server they are using is out of date on its time zone definitions, but still, there shouldn't be a 5 or 6 hour difference between actual UTC and what the server is giving me.

The CST part worked 2 weeks ago (i.e. before DST hit).

It is possible that the server owners made changes to their time zone settings, but that does not explain why the debug output returns UTC.

Can someone help me figure out what is going on here and how to make this work with daylight savings time?

Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't 8:11am CST when you posted this, it was 8:11am CDT.

Comment: If CST and CDT currently are 1h apart, how does this account for a 5 hour difference in my results?

Comment: I never suggested it did, just mentioning a mistake I noticed in your question,

Comment: I updated that part mentioning that in that line, I am using the colloquial version of CST.

Comment: What methods have you tried for (re)defining the `TZ` variable in the environment of your `date` command?  Have you tried setting it as a prefix on the `date` command line?  Have you set it *and `export`ed it* in the host shell?  Have you tried using the `env` command for the purpose?

Comment: I have tried setting it before `date`, and I have tried `export`. In both cases, the change did not take, and the system still returned `UTC`. I don't remember if I tried `env`, but doing some research pointed at the possibility of the time zone actually being set to read-only and unchangeable, so that is my best guess at this time. It still doesn't explain the new 5h difference...

Comment: @semmelbroesel, `TZ` is just an environment variable. It can be read-only in the sense that you are stuck using a shell that rejects attempts to set it or to pass it to commands, but there is no deeper sense in which an environment variable can be read-only.  The `env` command does not use the shell to set environment variables.  You might not have access to it, or the version you have might, separately, have its own restrictions, but `env TZ=America/Chicago date` and related commands are at least worth a try.

Comment: Actually, that's not exactly true.  Some shells do have a way to make environment variables read-only, but that's still a function of the shell, not anything deeper than that.

Comment: My previous research about read-only values related to `/etc/localtime` and `/etc/timezone` being write-protected. But maybe these are not related to `TZ`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible that the server owners made changes to their time zone settings, but that does not explain why the debug output returns UTC.

More likely, the change to DST in your area is what produced the breakage.

> I just ran some test code:
>
> ```
> now1=$(date '+%s' -d "now CST")
> now2=$(date '+%s' -d "now CDT")
>
> echo "Human readable times:"
> echo "Now CST: $(date -d @$now1)"
> echo "Now CDT: $(date -d @$now2)"
> ```
>
> It is currently 8:11am CST [edit: CST in colloquial terms, not in
> computer terms]. This should be 1:11pm UTC according to Google.
>
> The output when I convert the timestamp back into human readable:
>
> ```
> Now CST: Thu Mar 21 19:11:44 UTC 2024
> Now CDT: Thu Mar 21 18:11:44 UTC 2024
> ```
>
> So that is 7pm and 6pm instead of the expected 1pm.

The command ...

```
date '+%s' -d "now CDT"
```

... says "take the current local time, *reinterpret it as being expressed in CDT*, and print the corresponding timestamp."  If that makes you scratch your head, then it may make more sense if you think about what you would expect when an explicit time is specified instead of `now`; for example, `13:01:00 EDT`.

Such timestamps are defined relative to UTC, however, regardless of the local time zone, so the command ...

```
date -d @$now2
```

... says "expand variable `now2`, interpret the result as a timestamp (relative to UTC, regardless of local time zone), and print the resulting date and time in the default format."  The default format uses the local time zone, which in your case happens to be UTC.

Chaining those together produces what the time is / was / will be in the local time zone when the CDT time is what the local time is now.  That's a bit of a mouthful, so here's a breakdown:

- you ran the first `date` command at 13:11:44 according to the server's local time
- a timestamp corresponding to 13:11:44 CDT today was stored
- you read back that timestamp with the second `date` command, and asked for it to be formatted in the default format
- the default format uses the local time zone, which happens to be UTC in your case.  The UTC time corresponding to 13:11:44 CDT is 18:11:44 UTC, which is what was printed.

That's not what you wanted, of course.

Of course, you can, and I guess did, work with that by expressing your start and end times in UTC or in the server's local time zone, or with a fixed offset from one of those. But if the start and end times relevant to you are expressed in the local time of an area that observes different DST behavior than your time reference does than that breaks when the two time references diverge.

---

As far as I am aware, the only way to request `date` to format dates in a different zone than is specified in `/etc/localtime` is to use the `TZ` environment variable.  The conventional way to do that is to specify it as a command-line prefix:

```
TZ=America/Chicago date
```

That may not work if your shell is configured to prevent `TZ` being modified, and in that case it is worth trying to use `env` to bypass the shell for controlling `date`'s environment:

```
env TZ=America/Chicago date
```

In particular, that still works for me in a Bash shell in which I have used `declare -r TZ` to mark the `TZ` variable read-only.

If using `env` does not do the job then you probably need to explore alternatives to the `date` command.  For example, if you can run Python scripts then Python's rather more flexible date / time utilities could be [brought to bear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096669/2402272).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

I tried `env`, and it still doesn't work as expected.

I'm using it on the start date which is given to me in `America/Chicago` time, and the system returns it with the same numbers but `UTC` time zone identifier.


`start_date="03/21/2024 15:00:00"`

`start=$(env TZ=America/Chicago date '+%s' -d "$start_date")`

`echo "$(date -d @$start)"`

The output is:

`Thu Mar 21 15:00:00 UTC 2024`

I'd expect this to read `20:00:00 UTC`.

Am I missing something, or is `TZ` really locked down here?

Comment: @semmelbroesel, what you now describe does not match what I observe on my own system.  It's difficult to say whether it is `TZ` or `date` or `env`, or all of the above, that is being restricted on your server, but I'm prepared at this point to say that `date` is not going to do for you the job that you want it to do.  Unless you're prepared to manually adjust for DST twice a year, this is were we come to the "explore alternatives" part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I will have to try Python based on the link you provided.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again - I managed to create and implement a python script that does the job perfectly.