# How to get python to display the current Eastern time?

Tags: python, datetime, time

How can I get Python to display the time in Eastern?

I've looked over the python documentation but it's pretty confusing. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117514/how-do-i-use-timezones-with-a-datetime-object-in-python Basically, use UTC internally and use PyTZ to convert to a particular timezone when displaying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the package `pytz` if you'll be needing a lot of time zones, and you need to correctly handle the duplicate hour of daylight savings time (i.e. what happens from midnight to 1am).

For something simple though, it's easy enough to create your own time zone class:

```
import datetime

class EST5EDT(datetime.tzinfo):

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=-5) + self.dst(dt)

    def dst(self, dt):
        d = datetime.datetime(dt.year, 3, 8)        #2nd Sunday in March
        self.dston = d + datetime.timedelta(days=6-d.weekday())
        d = datetime.datetime(dt.year, 11, 1)       #1st Sunday in Nov
        self.dstoff = d + datetime.timedelta(days=6-d.weekday())
        if self.dston <= dt.replace(tzinfo=None) < self.dstoff:
            return datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        else:
            return datetime.timedelta(0)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return 'EST5EDT'

dt = datetime.datetime.now(tz=EST5EDT())
```

Here you are using the abstract base class `datetime.tzinfo` to create a `EST5EDT` class which describes what it means to be "Eastern Time Zone", namely your UTC offset (-5 hours) and when daylight savings time is in effect (btwn the 2nd Sunday of March and the 1st Sunday of November).

Btw the template above is pulled from the `datetime` docs:
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Not sure what you mean "get Python to display the time in eastern", but using the `dt` object from the last line above:

```
    In [15]: print(dt)
2012-07-29 12:28:59.125975-04:00

    In [16]: print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
2012-07-29 12:28:59

    In [17]: print(dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
12:28:59

    In [18]: print(dt.strftime('%s.%f'))  
1343579339.125975
```

Answer (score 53):

There is a much more intuitive way, of course:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
tz = timezone('EST')
datetime.now(tz) 
## this returns a datetime object pointing to right now 
## according to the timezone info object handed in as the tz variable.
```

Alternatively you can define your own `datetime` object and pass in `tz` as `tzinfo`, as you can see below:

```
datetime(2016, 3, 30, 11, 13, 24, tzinfo=tz)
```

Comment: This is exactly  what I was looking for. 

However I ran the above (date of this comment and I'm on the East Coast). And its showing the following (I'm guessing this is a daylight savings issues):
print datetime.now(tz) ---> Out[23]: datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 22, 12, 19, 20, 281778, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'EST'>)

print datetime.now() ----- > Out[24]: datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 22, 13, 19, 58, 839327)

Comment: Using 'US/Eastern' instead of 'EST' seems to resolve this

Comment: not sure what can cause a 38minute offset though it may be that your local system has a different set of timezones. for a list have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/python-pytz-list-of-timezones

Answer (score 6):

[Pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library should be useful. Using Pytz (supports > 2.3) below code can get you the time according to eastern timezone.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2012, 10, 29, 6, 0, 0))
print loc_dt.strftime(fmt)
```

Comment: I can't seem to install pytz, it's telling me to install via the command line but I have no idea how. I tried what the readme said: c:\python32\python.exe setup.py install. But it said invalid.

Comment: You may have a wrong version of pytz installed. Can you try using "easy_install --upgrade pytz" command. You should have setuptools installed for this.

Comment: I don't think setuptools is for Python 3, I can only find versions for Python 2.x.

Comment: [link]http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute You can use distribute in python 3 for setuptools.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't use pytz module and need simple solution then you can use

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime.now(timezone(timedelta(hours=-5), 'EST'))
```

Comment: As someone else pointed out, this won't account for daylight savings.

Comment: @1I1III1 the reason for "extra bloatware" is that it takes care of all the edge cases for you, hand crafted solutions such as this one tend to fail randomly. And as mentioned in the comment above me this does not take care of daylight saving...

Comment: @AKareem yeah, you're right. It's kind of funny that this answer and [the one below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40163812/3476782) have different time deltas because they were posted at different times of year. For context, this solution worked for me because I just needed it for a REPL input rather than a real system. I know I said bloatware, but I think I was actually frustrated with a `left-pad` type package mentality, where even one line solutions get turned into a (sometimes obscure) package import. I guess it isn't always the mistake I thought it was.

Answer (score -1):

If you need the entire timestamp:

```
import datetime
print (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=4))
```

If you just need the date in YYYYmmdd format

```
print (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=4)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: This incorrectly assumes that the eastern time zone is always offset from UTC by 4 hours.