# How do I implement 'tzinfo' to offset current GMT to EST (GMT -4:00)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, tzinfo

My function takes a UTC datetime string as a parameter, converts it to a datetime object which I then need to offset to EST(GMT -4:00). For example, passing “*2019-07-01T00:00:00Z*” to the function should return “*06/30/2019 08:00:00*”.

Here's how I implemented the subclass for '*tzinfo*' and its standard methods.

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta

class EST(tzinfo):

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "US/Eastern"

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=-4) + self.dst(dt)

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)


TEST_UTC = "2019-07-01T00:00:00Z"
dt_object = datetime.strptime(TEST_UTC, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")  # String to datetime object -> 2019-07-01 00:00:00
print(dt_object.astimezone(EST()))
```

The expected output for the last print statement is *2019-06-30 20:00:00-04:00* but the program returns *2019-06-30 14:30:00-04:00*. It shows the expected result only if I set the values in the 'timedelta' of the 'utcoffset' function to `timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30)`.

Please note I want to implement this using 'datetime' library only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I wrongly concluded that `print(dt_object.astimezone(EST()))` was implementing the offset of EST() class relative to the timestamp of `dt_object` assigned in the statement above. It was actually implementing according to the UTC time at the moment of running the code. So before implementing my class, I had to first set the timezone of `dt_object` to UTC and then offset it with `EST()`. Here's the code I used.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo, timezone

class EST(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=-4) + self.dst(dt)

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "US/Eastern"


def utc_to_eastern(utc_timestring):
    dt = datetime.strptime(utc_timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) # This was the step I missed earlier
    dt = dt.astimezone(EST())
    return dt


TEST_UTC = "2019-07-01T00:00:00Z"
print(utc_to_eastern(TEST_UTC))
```

**Note:** If you want to adjust for daylight saving as well using the `dst()` method, you can refer to this thread >> [How to get python to display current time (eastern)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710469/how-to-get-python-to-display-current-time-eastern)