# Convert "PST" to "US/Pacific" for use with Pytz

Tags: python, timezone, converters, pytz

I'm trying to create HTTP endpoints:

1. one that returns posts to a user that were created in a given month in the **requestor's time zone**.
2. another one that gets the *months* possible for post*.

### Examples

#### (1) get posts in month of requestor's timezone

#### (2) get possible months for posts

For example if the user made posts in `Sept-November` but none in `December` then `Jan` onward it wouldn't return `December`.
But it takes the time zone in `"PST"` format, because it does a **SQL query**.

### Problems

Unfortunately [`pytz`](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz), the library I'm using for getting all posts from a *month*, only accepts *time zone* in the format `"US/Pacific"`.

### Questions

1. What is the format or string representation `"US/Pacific"` called ?
2. How can I convert the string formats `"PST"`, `"UCT"` or `"CST"` to their respective formats like `"US/Pacific"`, etc. in Python ?
3. What's the name for this format like `"US/Pacific"` ?
4. Is there a sort of dictionary that maps `"PST"` to `"US/Pacific"` ?

Comment: Could you provide datasample for such timestamp coming from the API?

Comment: Don't forget Daylight Saving....

Comment: Also the problem you are facing might be related to Summer Time shift. PST is a short name for Pacific Time with Summer Time active while US/Pacific is not restricted to ST and will take account of ST when needed (at least in python).

Comment: @jlandercy sure. It'd be something like `month=1`, `year=2021` and `time_zone='PST'`

Comment: @jlandercy didn't know that. That's very nice.

Answer (score 4):

### Time zone terminology

How to define, represent or refer to a time zone? Some terms:

- [UTC time **offset**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) (e.g. "UTC-08:00")
- in relation with ISO 8601 date/time format: [time zone **designator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) (e.g. "Z" or "-08")
- time zone: canonical **name**
- time zone: **abbreviation**

#### (Canonical) names

The spelled-out *time zone names* or (tz names) like "US/Pacific" or "Europe/Paris" are also called **canonical names** of time zone. They are used as key in the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). In [RFC 6557](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6557.html) they are referred to as "time zone names". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#Legend) claims about them:

> The primary, preferred zone name.

See also:

- ECMA: [6.4Time Zone Names](https://402.ecma-international.org/2.0/#sec-time-zone-names)

#### Abbreviations

The alphabetic string literals like "UTC", "PST" are [**abbreviations** of *time zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Abbreviations).

### Conversion between time zones

Usually the conversion between time zones is done by modifying the *offsets of UTC* which are represented in [ISO 8601, time zone *designators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) like "-0800" ([PST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone)) which is 8 hours subtracted from "+0000" (UTC).

See also:

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices/2532962#2532962)

#### Converting using `pytz` timezone

To convert a given date-time from UTC to the target time zone (e.g. "US/Pacific") use [`astimezone(tz)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) on the source date-time instance:

```py
import datetime
from pytz import timezone, utc

utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

pst_tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
pst_time = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=utc).astimezone(pst_tz)
```

Note:

- the time-zone `tz` is built using pytz's [`tzinfo` API](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#tzinfo-api), e.g. with `timezone('PST8PDT')` for PST or `timezone('US/Central')` for CST
- the [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) is optional and resets the time zone of given date-time to default UTC.

**Surprisingly:** The "PST" abbreviation is not found in `pytz.all_timezones`. Most similar are (evaluated in REPL):

```
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.timezone('PST8PDT')
<DstTzInfo 'PST8PDT' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>
>>> pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' LMT-1 day, 16:07:00 STD>
>>> pytz.timezone('US/Central')
<DstTzInfo 'US/Central' LMT-1 day, 18:09:00 STD>
```

See also:

- [pytz - Converting UTC and timezone to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264811/pytz-converting-utc-and-timezone-to-local-time)
- [Is there a list of Pytz Timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones)

#### Converting using `zoneinfo` (since 3.9)

Adjusted from [MrFuppes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65087160/5730279) to "How do I use timezones with a datetime object in python?":

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

utc_time = datetime(2012,11,10,9,0,0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

cst_tz = ZoneInfo("US/Central")
cst_time = utc_time.astimezone(cst_tz)

# safely use `replace` to get the same wall time in a different tz:
pst_time = cst_time.replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("US/Pacific"))

print(utc_time.isoformat())
print(cst_time.isoformat())
print(pst_time.isoformat())
```

(above code is not tested!)

See also:

- new Python module [zoneinfo — IANA time zone support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)
- Paul Ganssle (2021): [Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html), blog article from the maintainer of `python-dateutil`

Comment: `timezone('PST')` gives `pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'PST'`

Comment: @user8714896 Thanks, did not test and expected the common abbreviation to be present. ️ Now it's tested + fixed ... and extended _terminology_ and new 3.9 module _zoneinfo_.

Comment: I was probably not explicit enough, I meant more like a string "PST" to "US/Pacific" not necessarily a timezone subclass

Comment: the problem with abbreviated tz names like "PST" is that at least some of them are ambiguous (e.g. search for "BST" ;-)) - That's why they're not supported by libraries such as pytz. A common way to remove that ambiguity is to define a mapping dict; e.g. mapping "PST" to "America/Los_Angeles". `dateutil`s [parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) can be fed with such a mapping for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime  # timezone

print('The supported tz:', pytz.all_timezones, '\n')
    
# Show date-time for different timezone/country
# current date and time of NY
datetime_NY = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
print("NY:", datetime_NY.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
# NY: 07/28/2021, 05:49:41

# Timezone Conversion
# Any timezone to UTC
NY_to_utc = datetime_NY.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print("NY_to_utc: ", NY_to_utc.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
# NY_to_utc:  07/28/2021, 09:49:41
```

[Naive and Aware datetime](https://shortandcrispy.com/post/python/moderate/02-timezone/) Refer this article for dealing with timezone

1. Show date-time for different timezone/country
2. Timezone Conversion
3. Timezone unaware/naive to Timezone aware
4. Issue with replace